# Group Wise total with CTE

Tags: sql-server

```
WITH cte AS
(
Select dbo.ParseEnum('LubeOilType',SL.LubeOilType) As MaterialName,
       SL.OpeningStock, 
       Closingstock = (Case When SL.LubeOilType = 0 Then DI1.EngineOilQty When SL.LubeOilType = 1 Then DI2.GearOilQty When SL.LubeOilType = 2 Then DI3.RearAxleOilQty End), SL.Remarks,
       SL.CreatedOn, SL.LastModifiedOn,
       ROWNUM = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by SL.LubeOilStockLedgerId ORDER BY SL.LubeOilStockLedgerId),
       ROWNUM2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SL.LubeOilStockLedgerId)
       from LubeOilStockLedger SL 
       Left join DailyLubeOilIssueRegister DI1 
       On SL.LubeOilStockLedgerId = DI1.EngineOilStockId 
       Left Join DailyLubeOilIssueRegister DI2
       On SL.LubeOilStockLedgerId = DI2.GearOilQtyStockId 
       Left Join DailyLubeOilIssueRegister DI3 
       On SL.LubeOilStockLedgerId = DI3.RearAxleOilStockId     
)
SELECT 
       MaterialName = c1.MaterialName,
       OpeningStock = c1.OpeningStock,
       Closingstock = c1.Closingstock,
       IssueQty = c1.Closingstock,
       Remarks = c1.Remarks,
       CreatedOn = c1.CreatedOn,
       LastModifiedOn = c1.LastModifiedOn,
       ROWNUM = c1.ROWNUM,
       ROWNUM2 = c1.ROWNUM2
FROM 
    cte
```

[image]

hi i want a query group wise some issue qty
like opening 10000  issue qty 4000 , remaing = (10000 - 4000) = 6000
10000  issue qty 100 then remaing =(1000 - (4000+100) = 5900

how it possible any one please solve for me help would be appreciated
Thanks.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are asking.  Can you use column names that match your example?

Comment: See the image row no1 engineoil opening stock = 10000, issue Qty = 4000, means closing stock = (10000 - 4000) = 6000

Answer (score 0):

It still isn't clear what you want, but best I can figure it sounds as if you are describing this:

```
Leftover = OpeningStock - SUM(IssueQty) over (partition by MaterialName ORDER BY CreatedON ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
```